# Atmega328p only one ISR handled

Tags: c, interrupt, avr, atmega, isr

I'm trying to run two functions 'similtaniously' via interrupts:

 1) Measure ADC via timing of timer 0 (100Hz) and show results on pin 0-5

 2) Blink a led via timer 1 (10Hz) on pin 6.

Problem seems to be that the ISR of timer 1 blocks the function, so nothing else is executed. Here is the code:

(Please don't be offended by any styling mistakes, the code is under development)

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL // 16MHz Clock speed 
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void ADC_init(void);
void SetTimer0(void);
void SetTimer1(void);

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= (1<<DDB0) + (1<<DDB1) + (1<<DDB2) + (1<<DDB3) + (1<<DDB4) + (1<<DDB5) + (1<<DDB6);
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    DDRB &= ~(1<<DDB7);

    ADC_init();
    SetTimer0();
    SetTimer1();

    while(1){
    }
}

void ADC_init(void)
{
    cli();
    // Select Vref=AVcc
    // and set left adjust result
    // select pin ADC0 (PC0)
    ADMUX |= (1<<REFS0)|(1<<ADLAR);

    //and enable ADC
    //enable ADC interupt   
    //enable autotriggering 
    //set prescaller to 128
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADEN) | (1<<ADATE) | (1<<ADIE) | (1<<ADPS2) | (1<<ADPS1) | (1<<ADPS0);

    //set ADC trigger source - Timer0 compare match A
    ADCSRB |= (1<<ADTS1)|(1<<ADTS0);

    // StartADC
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC); 

    sei();
}

//initialize timer0 match A on 100hz
void SetTimer0(void)
{   
    cli();
    TCCR0A = 0; // set entire TCCR0A register to 0
    TCCR0B = 0; // same for TCCR0B
    TCNT0  = 0; // initialize counter value to 0
    // set compare match register for 100Hz increments
    OCR0A = 155; // = 16000000 / (1024 * 100.16025641025641)-1
    // toggle PD6/OC0A pin on compare match
    TCCR0A |=(1<<COM0A0)|(1<<WGM01);    
    //Set CTC mode
    TCCR0B |= (1 << WGM01);
    // Set CS02, CS01 and CS00 bits for 1024 prescaler
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS02) | (0 << CS01) | (1 << CS00);
    // enable timer compare interrupt
    TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);
    sei();
}

//initialize timer1 10hz
void SetTimer1(void){
    cli();
    TCCR1A = 0; // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
    TCCR1B = 0; // same for TCCR1B
    TCNT1  = 0; // initialize counter value to 0
    // set compare match register for 10 Hz increments
    OCR1A = 24999; // = 16000000 / (64 * 10) - 1 (must be <65536)
    // turn on CTC mode
    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
    // Set CS12, CS11 and CS10 bits for 64 prescaler
    TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10);
    // enable timer compare interrupt
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
    sei();
}

// ADC done interrupt
ISR(ADC_vect)
{
    // Clear timer compare match flag
    TIFR0=(1<<OCF0A);

    // save ADC measurement
    uint16_t val = ADC;

    // show ADC results
    if (val < 100)
    { PORTB = 0b00000000; }
    else if (val < 300)
    { PORTB = 0b00000001; }
    else if (val < 550)
    { PORTB = 0b00000011; }
    else if (val < 850)
    { PORTB = 0b00000111; }
    else if (val < 1020)
    { PORTB = 0b00001111; }
    else 
    { PORTB = 0b00011111; }

}


ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    //PORTB ^= PINB5;
    static uint16_t on = 0;
    if (on == 1){
        PORTB = 0b00100000;
        on = 0;
    }
    else {
        PORTB = 0b00000000;
        on = 1;
    }
}
```

When the `SetTimer1()` function is disabled the DCA runs as expected. So individually are are both ISR's working fine, but together not. Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: dont forget its a single thread. no OS. for arduino. so if one ISR is consuming the cpu (and starve the other one), nothing will prevent it from running. else if you know how to habdle these cases.

Comment: @Adam thanks for mentioning it! Although I doubt that this process is consuming all CPU power.

Comment: just set a flag in your 100Hz event every 10th iteration and handle it in your main loop.

Comment: @atmel_joep if there is only one thread of execution (one core) then one thing can only run at one time and not conccurently. That's what Adam was saying.

Comment: @BaileyKocin I get the point but that's not how these microcontrollers are designed. The two timers can run independently from each other. The code behind the main loop is checking the interrupt flags to switch from main loop to ISR and back. It's not multithreading but the closest thing to it.

Comment: I am pretty sure, that you have to reset the TCNTn registers to 0 when hitting the ISR. Otherwise the counter will count up until it overflows and the next compare match will take much longer. And you should explain in detail what you are observing instead of "together not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have output compare interrupt enabled fro Timer0:

```
// enable timer compare interrupt
TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);
```

but no ISR handler for that interrupt.

The default *__bad_interrupt* handler just performs jump to zero interrupt vector, i.e. restarts the program.

That means if you have an interrupt enabled there should be an ISR for that interrupt.